# Best way for database connection from .rptdesign file in the WebApp to MySql Database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, birt

I am a newbie to BIRT and Java Development. And have created a BIRT report using `OpenText BIRT Designer` as per Client Requirement.

This report is fetching data from `Mysql Database` and it is working fine in `OpenText Birt Designer`.

I was able to run the reference Java WebApplication [Project](https://bitbucket.org/cirovladimir/birtviewerintegrationmvn/downloads) available online to access the BIRT report from within a Java WebApp. Report was generated successfully from within the WebApp, however the only problem is to connect  from `.rptDesign` file in WebApp to `MySql DataBase`.

Please help me to get the best way for database connection from  `.rptdesign` file in the WebApp to `MySql Database`.

Development Environment:

1. Netbeans 7.4
2. GlassFish Server
3. Open Text BIRT Designer 4.6